# How to get pixels on the circle detected on an image using OpenCv Hough Circle

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, pixel

i am using the following method to detect the circle on a image (android studio).

Comment: What do you mean by "occupied". the circle line, the circle area within, ...?

Comment: It is not contained into your Coinarea variable?

Comment: @Christopher, the area occupied within the detected circle outline. I am using the Coinarea variables fro the calculation, however i'm not sure if it is the correct way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers that i can deduce based on your question.

1. if you want the mathematical circle area: i guess you have already found it using the "Coinarea" variable
2. the number of pixels in that "Coinarea": "**countNonZero(Mat src)**"
     Counts non-zero array elements or precisely the count of non-zero pixel values in the matrix "src" that is provided as the input for the function.

Note: While it may not count zero pixel values, hence for some images the value it outputs might not be correct. use it only when you know that the source area will always have non zero values.

Comment: does my Coinarea variable mean the number of pixels occupied by the coin detected within the circle outline? i am not sure about this